# superscripting a dot which is enclosed in square brackets

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, text-decorations

This question is about how to extend the nice answer here by @egreg
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304078/103130

to the following case (which is close to what I need except that the brackets should appear around the dot, and the brackets should be a bit closer together):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\boverdot{}

\DeclareRobustCommand\boverdot[1]{\mathord{\mathpalette\b@dot{#1}}}
\newcommand{\b@dot}[2]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\dot{#2}$}%
    \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{\scalebox{.5}[.2]{$\m@th#1[$}}%
    \copy\z@
    \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{\scalebox{.5}[.2]{$\m@th#1]$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a_{\boverdot{i}}$

\end{document}
```

Can anyone see how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Extra credit if anyone can come up with a solution that only uses amsmath and graphicx packages!

Answer (score 2):

I adapted `\bunderline` from my answer ([putting square brackets around the underline of a letter (in math mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304070/putting-square-brackets-around-the-underline-of-a-letter-in-math-mode/304075#304075)) at the cited question into `\boverdot`.  It works in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel,amsmath}
\stackMath
\def\tinylb{\smash{\scalebox{.25}{$\SavedStyle[$}}}
\def\tinyrb{\smash{\scalebox{.25}{$\SavedStyle]$}}}
\def\bunderline#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackunder[1.2pt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\tinylb\rule[.3\LMpt]{\wd0}{.4pt}\tinyrb}}}
\def\boverdot#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackon[-1.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\dot#1}{\tinylb\rule[0.3\LMpt]{\wd0}{0pt}\tinyrb}}}
\let\overdot\dot
\begin{document}
$ a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{i},\boverdot{i},d $

$ \scriptstyle 
  a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{i},\boverdot{i},d $

$ \scriptscriptstyle 
  a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{i},\boverdot{i},d $
\end{document}
```

[image]

To bring the brackets a bit closer, multiply `\wd0` in the definition of `\boverdot` by a value less than one, in this case `.5`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel,amsmath}
\stackMath
\def\tinylb{\smash{\scalebox{.25}{$\SavedStyle[$}}}
\def\tinyrb{\smash{\scalebox{.25}{$\SavedStyle]$}}}
\def\bunderline#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackunder[1.2pt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\tinylb\rule[.3\LMpt]{\wd0}{.4pt}\tinyrb}}}
\def\boverdot#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackon[-1.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\dot#1}{\tinylb\rule[0.3\LMpt]{.5\wd0}{0pt}\tinyrb}}}
\let\overdot\dot
\begin{document}
$ a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{i},\boverdot{i},d $

$ \scriptstyle 
  a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{i},\boverdot{i},d $

$ \scriptscriptstyle 
  a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{i},\boverdot{i},d $
\end{document}
```

[image]

The non-centered dot above the `g` is a function of special letter-specific  kerning associated with the `\dot` macro.  The following avoids that problem by forcing the overdot to be centered over the letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel,amsmath}
\stackMath
\def\tinylb{\smash{\scalebox{.25}{$\SavedStyle[$}}}
\def\tinyrb{\smash{\scalebox{.25}{$\SavedStyle]$}}}
\def\bunderline#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackunder[1.2pt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\tinylb\rule[.3\LMpt]{\wd0}{.4pt}\tinyrb}}}
\def\boverdot#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackon[1.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{%
    \tinylb\smash{\raisebox{-1.8\LMpt}{\makebox[.5\wd0]{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}}}\tinyrb}}}
\let\overdot\dot
\begin{document}
$ a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{\imath},\boverdot{\imath},d $

$ \scriptstyle 
  a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{\imath},\boverdot{\imath},d $

$ \scriptscriptstyle 
  a,\overdot{b},\boverdot{b},\overdot{g},\boverdot{g},
 \overdot{\imath},\boverdot{\imath},d $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks! How could I reduce the spacing between the square brackets to bring them closer together?

Comment: @user103130 Multiply `\wd0` in the `\boverdot` definition.  See my revision.

Comment: spaces between dot and brackets not symmetrical over the "g".  and maybe `\imath` instead of undotted "i"?

Comment: Thanks again Steven! I'm curious why the dot is sometimes not equidistant from the square brackets, but other times it is. Do happen to know how the brackets could be centered properly?

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I am aware of the `g` asymmetry.  However, it arises because there must be glyph-unique kerns for the dots over various letters, to which my algorithm does not have access.

Comment: does that mean that it is the dot which is off-center over the g, rather than the brackets being off-center?

Comment: @user103130 Yes.

Comment: is there a dot that is always centered over a letter (in math mode)?

Comment: Nearly perfect! I think the only way this solution could be better is if it only used the amsmath and graphicx packages.

Comment: I just noticed that the brackets are around the dot that is part of the letter i. I wanted to add an extra bracketed dot above the i.

Comment: @user103130 It was at barbara's suggestion that I changed instances of `i` to `\imath`.  You can change that back when you use it.  It is not part of the macro definition.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution also changes the vertical position of the subscripted letter. Compare `$a_{\boverdot{i}}$` to `$a_{i}$`. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution also works for you ? It seems to be a lot simpler and the result seems to be the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\boverdot}[1]{\overset{\scalebox{.5}[.2]{$[$} \boldsymbol{.} \scalebox{.5}[.2]{$]$}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
$a_{\boverdot{i}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution changes the height of the subscripted letter. Also, the square brackets are a bit too far apart. However, it is really nice that this only uses the amsmath and graphicx packages

Comment: By "height", I really meant vertical position. :) The subscripted letter gets moved down.